# Change text inside touchable opacity on click

Tags: react-native, text, touchableopacity

I want to change the text inside my touchable opacity to another text on press event. Below is my code

```
<TouchableOpacity
        disabled={this.state.ButtonStateHolder}
        onPress={this.onPressConfirm}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        <View
          style={[
            styles.button1,
            {
              backgroundColor: this.state.ButtonStateHolder
                ? "#607D8B"
                : "#8c0d04"
            }
          ]}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttontext}>Confirm</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Here I want to changethe text confirm to Parked on press event. How do I do that

Comment: Do you want to change the `Confirm` text?

Comment: Yes and also the current backgroundColor is #8c0d04 so when I click I want to lower the opacity of #8c0d04 instead of changing it to "#607D8B"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initialize the state text to `'Confirm'`. And the TouchableOpacity will be like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    disabled={this.state.ButtonStateHolder}
    onPress={() => {this.setState({text: 'Parked'})}}
    style={styles.button}
>
    <View
        style={[
            styles.button1,
            {
                backgroundColor: this.state.ButtonStateHolder
                    ? "#8c0d0488"
                    : "#8c0d04ff"
            }
        ]}
    >
        <Text style={styles.buttontext}>{this.state.text}</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Note the last byte added to the colors. The `FF` means full opacity. And the `88` means half opacity.

Comment: Hey one more thing, I have calculated time like this
const time = moment(this.props.datetime).format("HH:mm A"); 
I want to add 12hr to my calculated time and print it in the same format as above. How to do that?

Comment: You can use add function `moment(this.props.datetime).add(12, 'hours')`